# Can a linked list node contain more than one data field?

Tags: c, list

I'm rather asking if it makes sense to do this. I have not seen any examples of this but I haven't seen anything that goes against this idea.

I am in a publisher-subscriber model, so the idea I have so far is: I create a list of topics, that are added from a certain file.

But instead of simply having each name of the topic and the pointer to the next topic, I kind of wanted to have a node of suscribers to each topic, in each topic's node.

Since I'm probably explaining myself poorly, this would be the idea:

```
struct topicNode{
char * topicName; //I believe there is no problem with pointers in a lists but again, I have not seen anyone doing it either so...

struct suscriberNode;
struct topicNode next;
};
```

And so I would make, if there's any suscriber to a certain topic, a list of suscribers for that topic. I've done similar things to this in Java, but I'm worried it's not such a good idea to this in C.

Comment: Yes they can....the bare minimum is the node and the next node information....as long as you satisfy that, you can have more if you want....these kind of things are better done in an OO-language though (but you can still use C, no harm)

Comment: yep that was my concern, I've used them in java a couple times but every single example in C was showing a single data field, so I got concerned about if I was missing some concept.

Thanks! and for user3121, you're completly right, I wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a single linked list can contain any data

```
------------------------------              ------------------------------
|              |             |            \ |              |             |
|     DATA     |     NEXT    |--------------|     DATA     |     NEXT    |
|              |             |            / |              |             |
------------------------------              ------------------------------
```

ref : http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists

Data can be an int, a struct, anything really.
Even 2 fields or 3 or 4 or ....

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

is a classic example 
but

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    int anotherval;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

is just as good. val and anotherval belong to the data in the picture and as I said it can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

So I understand you have topics and subscribers that can subscribe to topics. Reading it in statically will cause no problem; however, when both topics and subscribers and their subscriptions can change, you wil want to "design" a data structure (with code to process it) that allows for this dynamics in an efficient manner.

Probably the best way is to have them cross-linked. The following data structures allow this:

```
typedef struct TOPIC {          // these are all the topics. Topics can be added or removed
    char *name;
    struct SUBSCR_LIST *subscribers;
    struct TOPIC *next;
} tTopic;

typedef struct SUBSCRIBER {     // these are all the subscribers. Subscribers can be added or removed
    char *name;
    struct TOPIC_LIST *topics;
    struct SUBSCRIBER *next;
} tSubscriber;

typedef struct SUBSCR_LIST {    // this list is part of a topic: who has subscribed?
    struct SUBSCRIBER *subscriber;
    struct SUBSCR_LIST *next;
} tSubscr_list;

typedef struct TOPIC_LIST {     // this list is part of a subscriber: what did he subscribe to?
    struct TOPIC *topic;
    struct TOPIC_LIST *next;
} tTopic_list;
```

You create two lists, one for the topics, and one for the subscribers. These are your main data. Each topic has a list of subscribers. When a subscriber subscribes to a topic, you add a pointer to the subscriber to the subscriber list of the topic. The other way around, each subscriber has a list of pointers to the topics they have subscribed to. When a subscriber subscribes to a topic, you also add a pointer to the topic to the topic list of the subscriber.

When now either a topic or a subscriber is removed (that is, the topic/the subscriber no longer exists), you use the pointers to remove their subscriptions.

EDIT/ADDITION:

You will want to maintain a list with each Topic about who is subscribed so you can notify these subscribers about news in his subscribed topics. You will want to maintain a list of Topics with each Subscriber, so the subscriber can go to his subscribed topics and can manage his subscriptions.

In addition, this cross-linking allows for efficient management when Topics and Subscribers are removed. Just think, suppose you only have a list of subscribers with each topic; now a subscriber is removed: you will have to search all lists of all topics to see if the subscriber is there and remove him. Would you have had a list of topics with the subscriber, you only need to walk that list to find the topics of the subscriber and remove the entry from the topic's list.

Comment: may I ask you a few things? This seems more complex than what I had in mind. Thing is, from my limited point of view, I don't get why do it in both directions? 

In my mind, if I do have a list of topics, and from each topic, a lists of suscribers, and I do everything right, it's good. With your implementation, I would have to do at least twice the work isnt it? To remove from both lists since now they would go in both directions. Something like that? Not quite sure

Comment: Note: my addition starts with a functional description and then argues why this is an efficient data structure. However, if your functional requirements are different, then another data structure can be feasible too, of course.